# C++: Write to an existing file?

Tags: c++

In C++, I need to write to an existing file and keep the previous content there.

This is what I have done:

```
std::ofstream logging;

logging.open(FILENAME);

logging << "HELLO\n";

logging.close();
```

but then my previous text is overwritten (gone). What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
logging.open(FILENAME, std::ios_base::app);
```

Comment: logging.open(FILENAME, std::ios::append|std::ate);  will always add to end also

Answer (score 3):

You have to open the file in append mode:

```
logging.open(FILENAME, std::ios::app);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the "[opening mode](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/ios_base/openmode)" for a file is overwrite.  Try opening the file in append mode

The second parameter of `open` is an enum bitflag.  The two options you should check out are:

- app - seek to the file end before each write
- ate - seek to the file end after open

  logging.open(FILENAME, std::ios::app|std::ate);

Answer (score 0):

do you try ?
something like that

```
myFile.open( "file.txt", ios::out | ios::app );
```